# Remap characters in a TTF or OTF file

Tags: fonts, typefaces

I've noticed that some of my typefaces have weird character mapping. For example, I have a few types designed by Dieter Steffmann, whose work is beautiful, but whose mapping is somewhat unorthodox (eg. his ſ is often mapped to a +).

Is there any way to remap certain characters without typecasting software?

Comment: If you have a legal copy of such a font, it's perfectly okay to ask the publisher for a Unicode-compliant version. The worst thing they can do is say "no".

Comment: @RadLexus, I've read through his EULA and remapping doesn't violate that. Regardless, this is about how to do so practically, rather than getting into legal theory (in which case it would fall under Law.SE instead)

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you would violate the EULA, but asking the publisher. That is probably not illegal.

Comment: @RadLexus, the same question would hold true of if I were to create my own type, lose the original files, and realise that I need to remap what I have.

Comment: NoahM, I think @RadLexus is simply suggesting you could ask the original author to do the modifications for you if you can't do it yourself (regardless of any legal implications). Which probably *is* the most practical solution in most cases (assuming you don't have font editing software)

Comment: If you’re worried about the expense of the software, FontForge (https://fontforge.github.io/en-US/) is free, and you can use it to fix encoding problems easily.

Comment: @Thérèse, I've had significant problems with FontForge in the past and AFAIK, that's the only Mac-compatible "font editor"

Comment: @Cai, if I could find an email address for the typecutter, I would

Comment: How about TruFont (https://trufont.github.io/)?

Answer (score 1):

FontForge is open-source and would let you do this. Failing that, you could write out your text and use a macro for find/replace.

Comment: See the comments above.